# Gdm new user set default desktop

Tags: users, .desktop, gdm, default, session

With gdm preferred, how do I get the new user to log in as cinnamon desktop instead of gnome desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created the new user,

for example if the user name is `cinnamon`

open the file with below command

```
sudo -H gedit /var/lib/AccountsService/users/cinnamon
```

and add the line `XSession=cinnamon` ( if the XSesson line is already there with empty then edit the line to look like XSession=cinnamon)

below is an example..

```
[User]
Session=cinnamon
XSession=cinnamon
Icon=/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/cinnamon
SystemAccount=false
```

Comment: So how will things work on the computer connected to the domain? When using lightdm, I can edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm-greeter.conf and get results. Can something like this be done for GDM as well?